Nuxt 3 SSR Not Displaying Custom Error Page on Server API Endpoint Failure
I'm encountering an issue with my Nuxt 3 SSR application where the custom error page (https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#error-page) does not display when a server API endpoint fails and throws an error using createError. I've also tried to pass the fatal option to createError, as true or false. Instead of seeing the custom error page, I'm presented with the Chrome browser error page.
// server/api/test.index.get
throw createError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: 'NOT_FOUND' });

// pages/index.vue
const { data, error } = await useFetch('/api/test');

if (error.value) {
  throw createError({
     statusCode: error.value.statusCode,
     message: error.value.message
  });
}

// error.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { NuxtError } from '#app';

interface Props {
    error: NuxtError;
}

defineProps<Props>();

const handleError = () => clearError({ redirect: '/' });
</script>

<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <div>
            <h2>{{ error.statusCode }}</h2>
            <button @click="handleError">Clear errors</button>
        </div>
    </NuxtLayout>
    <Toaster />
</template>


This happens regardless of whether the error is a 404 or a 500. Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to ensure that the custom error page is displayed correctly when an API endpoint fails?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
UPDATE:
It seems to be this server plugin that uses the h3-compression package that causes the issue. I'm not sure how to fix it though.
// server/plugins/compression.ts

import { useCompression } from 'h3-compression';

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitro) => {
    nitro.hooks.hook('render:response', async (response, { event }) => {
        if (!response.headers?.['content-type']?.startsWith('text/html')) return;

        await useCompression(event, response);
    });
});


SOLUTION:
Change the content of server/plugins/compression.ts to this:
import { useCompression } from 'h3-compression';

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitro) => {
    nitro.hooks.hook('render:response', async (response, { event }) => {
        if (response.headers?.['content-type'].startsWith('text/html') && !event?.context?.matchedRoute?.path.startsWith('/__nuxt')) {
            await useCompression(event, response);
        }
    });
});


Issue: https://github.com/CodeDredd/h3-compression/issues/4

Hi can you tell me what is shown in this Chrome browser error page? also can you tell me the errors shown in the console of the server (the terminal where you run the nuxt app, not the console in the browser)?

@Damzaky
The Chrome browser error page shows (translated):
"This page from  was not found.
No webpage found on webaddress: .
HTTP ERROR 404."
In the terminal this error is logged: [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/sddfsdf"

hmm, are you running it on local? is this location /sddfsdf accessible if you don't throw error in it? also is /sddfsdf a page or an api?

@Damzaky It happens both locally and in production. /sddfsdf is not a page or API, just a random URL I typed to hit a 404.

@Damzaky Now that I think about it, it seems like the error page isn't working correctly, with or without an API endpoint being called. No API is called on the /sddfsdf on route because it doesn't exist, but still the Chrome error page is shown and not the custom Nuxt error page. I have placed a error.vue in the root of my project (toget with app.vue) like the documentation shows. Do you know why that is? :)

in that case, there's a chance that your error.vue file is not working, what happen if you, for instance, rename that file to errorx.vue?

@Damzaky I found the issue and solution. I have updated my question. Thank you very much for the help!

well the solution is in the github issue you included actually lol

@Damzaky Yes :D

I posted an answer for this so that your reputation points are not lost for no reason.

Based on this comment, this is how you solve the issue.
import { useCompression } from 'h3-compression'

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitro) => {
  nitro.hooks.hook('render:response', async (response, { event }) => {
    if (response.headers?.['content-type'].startsWith('text/html') && !event?.context?.matchedRoute?.path.startsWith('/__nuxt')) {
      await useCompression(event, response)
    }
  })
})

